# random effects structure with weird residual plot

Tags: nlme, random-effects, glmm

So We are triying to fit a glmm to my_data. [my_data](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1YvLWbUZEkKtK-D3GWsFZm6nrpNiQ5dgv/view?usp=drive_link)

Figure [Figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t9iGq.jpg) resume the descriptive statistic of my_data. D0.Richness is unbalanced (n=sample size for each Group1 level) as we can see in figure. Then we fit data in nlme:

> m.1.a = lme(D0_.Riqueza.~Tratamento+Sistema*Tempo*Temperatura, random = ~1|Tank/Sample, data = my_data,  control =list(msMaxIter = 1000, msMaxEval = 1000))

```
Linear mixed-effects model fit by REML
  Data: my_data 
       AIC      BIC    logLik
  728.1183 775.5072 -344.0591

Random effects:
 Formula: ~1 | Tank
        (Intercept)
StdDev:    9.578657

 Formula: ~1 | Sample %in% Tank
        (Intercept) Residual
StdDev:    14.19689 5.685644

Fixed effects:  D0_.Riqueza. ~ Tratamento + Sistema * Tempo * Temperatura 
                                            Value Std.Error DF    t-value p-value
(Intercept)                             -883.5998 1498.9767 72 -0.5894687  0.5574
TratamentoControl                         -0.3201    7.8723  7 -0.0406651  0.9687
SistemaBiofloco                          467.9542 1508.0596  7  0.3103022  0.7654
TempoDay06                              1729.2678 1045.7843 72  1.6535607  0.1026
TempoDay11                               890.5315 1459.7221 72  0.6100692  0.5437
TempoDay30                               575.8523 1283.1337 72  0.4487859  0.6549
Temperatura                               28.1173   46.0317 72  0.6108247  0.5432
SistemaBiofloco:TempoDay06             -1090.8551 1069.6759 72 -1.0197996  0.3112
SistemaBiofloco:TempoDay11               -10.2688 1477.1431 72 -0.0069518  0.9945
SistemaBiofloco:TempoDay30              -210.7544 1297.7599 72 -0.1623986  0.8714
SistemaBiofloco:Temperatura              -14.3765   46.2605 72 -0.3107720  0.7569
TempoDay06:Temperatura                   -59.7401   31.9417 72 -1.8702879  0.0655
TempoDay11:Temperatura                   -26.9311   50.7368 72 -0.5308009  0.5972
TempoDay30:Temperatura                   -16.4391   43.8698 72 -0.3747247  0.7090
SistemaBiofloco:TempoDay06:Temperatura    39.3035   32.9882 72  1.1914422  0.2374
SistemaBiofloco:TempoDay11:Temperatura    -0.7773   51.3028 72 -0.0151506  0.9880
SistemaBiofloco:TempoDay30:Temperatura     6.3729   44.3377 72  0.1437347  0.8861
 Correlation: 
                                       (Intr) TrtmnC SstmBf TmpD06 TmpD11 TmpD30 Tmprtr SsB:TD06 SsB:TD11 SsB:TD30 SstB:T TD06:T
TratamentoControl                       0.425                                                                                   
SistemaBiofloco                        -0.992 -0.419                                                                            
TempoDay06                             -0.786 -0.230  0.781                                                                     
TempoDay11                             -0.162  0.072  0.162  0.341                                                              
TempoDay30                             -0.171  0.090  0.170  0.381  0.357                                                       
Temperatura                            -1.000 -0.428  0.992  0.786  0.162  0.170                                                
SistemaBiofloco:TempoDay06              0.768  0.223 -0.774 -0.977 -0.334 -0.373 -0.768                                         
SistemaBiofloco:TempoDay11              0.158 -0.076 -0.167 -0.336 -0.989 -0.354 -0.158  0.343                                  
SistemaBiofloco:TempoDay30              0.165 -0.097 -0.178 -0.375 -0.354 -0.989 -0.165  0.382    0.362                         
SistemaBiofloco:Temperatura             0.992  0.419 -1.000 -0.781 -0.162 -0.170 -0.992  0.774    0.167    0.178                
TempoDay06:Temperatura                  0.607  0.123 -0.603 -0.968 -0.374 -0.421 -0.606  0.946    0.369    0.415    0.603       
TempoDay11:Temperatura                  0.032 -0.129 -0.032 -0.241 -0.991 -0.339 -0.031  0.236    0.980    0.336    0.032  0.298
TempoDay30:Temperatura                  0.037 -0.150 -0.037 -0.279 -0.340 -0.991 -0.036  0.273    0.337    0.981    0.037  0.344
SistemaBiofloco:TempoDay06:Temperatura -0.587 -0.119  0.593  0.937  0.362  0.408  0.587 -0.969   -0.372   -0.417   -0.593 -0.968
SistemaBiofloco:TempoDay11:Temperatura -0.030  0.132  0.037  0.238  0.981  0.336  0.029 -0.245   -0.992   -0.343   -0.037 -0.294
SistemaBiofloco:TempoDay30:Temperatura -0.033  0.156  0.045  0.274  0.337  0.981  0.033 -0.283   -0.344   -0.991   -0.045 -0.340
                                       TD11:T TD30:T SB:TD06: SB:TD11:
TratamentoControl                                                     
SistemaBiofloco                                                       
TempoDay06                                                            
TempoDay11                                                            
TempoDay30                                                            
Temperatura                                                           
SistemaBiofloco:TempoDay06                                            
SistemaBiofloco:TempoDay11                                            
SistemaBiofloco:TempoDay30                                            
SistemaBiofloco:Temperatura                                           
TempoDay06:Temperatura                                                
TempoDay11:Temperatura                                                
TempoDay30:Temperatura                  0.339                         
SistemaBiofloco:TempoDay06:Temperatura -0.288 -0.333                  
SistemaBiofloco:TempoDay11:Temperatura -0.990 -0.336  0.298           
SistemaBiofloco:TempoDay30:Temperatura -0.337 -0.991  0.343    0.343  

Standardized Within-Group Residuals:
         Min           Q1          Med           Q3          Max 
-0.964339023 -0.204337214  0.001215562  0.178330841  1.035617143 

Number of Observations: 96
Number of Groups: 
            Tank Sample %in% Tank 
              10               96 $

r.squaredGLMM(m.1.a)*100
          R2m      R2c
[1,] 37.35081 93.78055
```

#"Sample" is a unique individual. Individuals were measured just once. It was considered random intercept of each sample nested in Tank. Eventually it was considered a random slope by Tempo (~Tempo|Tank/Sample), but nlme give a error message "Error in lme.formula(D0_.Riqueza. ~ Tratamento + Sistema * Tempo + Tempo *  :
fewer observations than random effects in all level 2 groups".

Question 1: Is valid the structure of our random effects (nesting each "Sample" within its respective "Tank")?

Question 2: Why the residual plot of "m.1.a" [residual.m.1.a](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V8YYW.jpg) does display a linear beahvior? Is it because the random effect structure apllied?

So We tried with other random efects structure, avoid nesting:

> m.1.b = lme(D0_.Riqueza.~Tratamento+Sistema*Tempo*Temperatura, random = ~ Tempo|Tank, data = my_data,  control =list(msMaxIter = 1000, msMaxEval = 1000))

```
Linear mixed-effects model fit by REML
  Data: my_data 
       AIC      BIC    logLik
  742.6198 808.9644 -343.3099

Random effects:
 Formula: ~Tempo | Tank
 Structure: General positive-definite, Log-Cholesky parametrization
            StdDev    Corr                
(Intercept)  8.240640 (Intr) TmpD06 TmpD11
TempoDay06   5.070250  0.510              
TempoDay11   6.103859  0.875  0.863       
TempoDay30   6.964783 -0.416 -0.994 -0.804
Residual    14.848455                     

Fixed effects:  D0_.Riqueza. ~ Tratamento + Sistema * Tempo * Temperatura 
                                            Value Std.Error DF    t-value p-value
(Intercept)                             -699.2080 1353.0931 72 -0.5167479  0.6069
TratamentoControl                          1.9563    7.2293  7  0.2706094  0.7945
SistemaBiofloco                          300.5875 1360.6927  7  0.2209077  0.8315
TempoDay06                              1659.6087  995.3994 72  1.6672791  0.0998
TempoDay11                               920.8840 1701.0956 72  0.5413476  0.5899
TempoDay30                               609.2401 1518.2923 72  0.4012667  0.6894
Temperatura                               22.4262   41.5534 72  0.5396953  0.5911
SistemaBiofloco:TempoDay06             -1025.2037 1022.8656 72 -1.0022858  0.3196
SistemaBiofloco:TempoDay11               -31.1847 1717.5524 72 -0.0181565  0.9856
SistemaBiofloco:TempoDay30              -263.6907 1532.1944 72 -0.1721000  0.8638
SistemaBiofloco:Temperatura               -9.2445   41.7400 72 -0.2214774  0.8253
TempoDay06:Temperatura                   -58.6019   32.7316 72 -1.7903776  0.0776
TempoDay11:Temperatura                   -28.8282   60.9389 72 -0.4730668  0.6376
TempoDay30:Temperatura                   -18.3361   50.9577 72 -0.3598304  0.7200
SistemaBiofloco:TempoDay06:Temperatura    38.1812   33.8937 72  1.1264979  0.2637
SistemaBiofloco:TempoDay11:Temperatura     0.6981   61.4697 72  0.0113569  0.9910
SistemaBiofloco:TempoDay30:Temperatura     8.8940   51.4277 72  0.1729427  0.8632
 Correlation: 
                                       (Intr) TrtmnC SstmBf TmpD06 TmpD11 TmpD30 Tmprtr SsB:TD06 SsB:TD11 SsB:TD30 SstB:T TD06:T
TratamentoControl                       0.433                                                                                   
SistemaBiofloco                        -0.992 -0.424                                                                            
TempoDay06                             -0.651 -0.222  0.646                                                                     
TempoDay11                              0.130  0.057 -0.129  0.319                                                              
TempoDay30                             -0.358  0.070  0.357  0.218  0.023                                                       
Temperatura                            -1.000 -0.435  0.992  0.651 -0.130  0.358                                                
SistemaBiofloco:TempoDay06              0.633  0.215 -0.639 -0.973 -0.311 -0.213 -0.633                                         
SistemaBiofloco:TempoDay11             -0.129 -0.057  0.123 -0.316 -0.990 -0.023  0.129  0.324                                  
SistemaBiofloco:TempoDay30              0.350 -0.081 -0.361 -0.214 -0.024 -0.992 -0.349  0.217    0.029                         
SistemaBiofloco:Temperatura             0.992  0.424 -1.000 -0.646  0.129 -0.357 -0.992  0.639   -0.123    0.361                
TempoDay06:Temperatura                  0.422  0.110 -0.419 -0.963 -0.428 -0.133 -0.421  0.937    0.423    0.131    0.419       
TempoDay11:Temperatura                 -0.227 -0.099  0.225 -0.248 -0.995  0.013  0.227  0.242    0.986   -0.011   -0.225  0.378
TempoDay30:Temperatura                  0.264 -0.118 -0.263 -0.157 -0.038 -0.995 -0.263  0.153    0.038    0.987    0.263  0.093
SistemaBiofloco:TempoDay06:Temperatura -0.408 -0.108  0.412  0.930  0.413  0.129  0.407 -0.964   -0.426   -0.133   -0.412 -0.966
SistemaBiofloco:TempoDay11:Temperatura  0.225  0.098 -0.219  0.246  0.987 -0.013 -0.225 -0.255   -0.995    0.007    0.219 -0.374
SistemaBiofloco:TempoDay30:Temperatura -0.256  0.129  0.267  0.152  0.038  0.987  0.256 -0.156   -0.043   -0.995   -0.267 -0.091
                                       TD11:T TD30:T SB:TD06: SB:TD11:
TratamentoControl                                                     
SistemaBiofloco                                                       
TempoDay06                                                            
TempoDay11                                                            
TempoDay30                                                            
Temperatura                                                           
SistemaBiofloco:TempoDay06                                            
SistemaBiofloco:TempoDay11                                            
SistemaBiofloco:TempoDay30                                            
SistemaBiofloco:Temperatura                                           
TempoDay06:Temperatura                                                
TempoDay11:Temperatura                                                
TempoDay30:Temperatura                  0.011                         
SistemaBiofloco:TempoDay06:Temperatura -0.365 -0.090                  
SistemaBiofloco:TempoDay11:Temperatura -0.991 -0.011  0.378           
SistemaBiofloco:TempoDay30:Temperatura -0.012 -0.992  0.093    0.016  

Standardized Within-Group Residuals:
        Min          Q1         Med          Q3         Max 
-2.42113917 -0.54063148 -0.02540128  0.43542432  2.86898537 

Number of Observations: 96
Number of Groups: 10 
> r.squaredGLMM(m.1.b)*100
          R2m      R2c
[1,] 36.54991 58.24922
```

Actually, we compare both models:

```
 anova(m.1.a, m.1.b)
      Model df      AIC      BIC    logLik   Test  L.Ratio p-value
m.1.a     1 20 728.1183 775.5072 -344.0591                        
m.1.b     2 28 742.6198 808.9644 -343.3099 1 vs 2 1.498451  0.9927
```

Despite there were no differences between models (although AIC and BIC was lower for m.1.a), residual plot (m.1.b) was different (and "better") [residual.m.1.b](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DBdR0.jpg).

Should we keep model m.1.a? If so, is there a way to understand and improve the residuals behavior of m.1.a? Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fitting a random effect where there's only one observation per block severely reduces the identifiability of your model: the random effect is directly competing with your residual error and nothing else. This is also the reason why you can't add a second random effect parameter, there's just no additional degrees of freedom to fit it - not that it would make any sense.

While you haven't explained your experimental setup or hypothesis in much detail the second model seems to make a lot more sense, where the random effect will handle the between-tank variability and the residual is subject within tank. In the second model you should also be able to add a random slope without issues (both for producing the fit and its interpretation).

Comment: Hi!, thanks for your comments. So the first one has reduced identifiability. Perhaps if there were repetition for each "Sample" (similar to tank), it will be more reliable. No I can see it.  Regarding about "In the second model you should also be able to add a random slope without issues", I was thinking of "random = ~ Tempo|Tank" means random intercept (by tank) and random slopes (by Tempo). am I wrong? Our hypothesis is "Riqueza" behavior (number of bacteria species suspended on water) is affected by "Tratamento" (presence-ATB or absence-Controle of antibiotic dissolved in water).

Comment: No, you're right - your second model did already include within each tank a random intercept and a random slope over Tempo.